# How to change last two column colors in sparkline charts

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, vlookup, sparklines

In Google Sheets, sparkline charts is known to have an option to change the last column color.

> =sparkline((A1:A5),{"charttype","column";"lastcolor","green"})[image]

What if I want to change last two column colors?  Any option like this, or any workaround?

> =sparkline((A1:A5),{"charttype","column";"lasttwocolor","green"})
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternative with SPARKLINE and some column width magic:

```
=INDEX({SPARKLINE(A1:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))-1), 
 {"charttype", "column"; "lastcolor", "green"; "ymax", LOOKUP(9^9, A:A)}), 
 SPARKLINE(OFFSET(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))-1, ), 
 {"charttype", "column"; "color", "green"})})
```

[image]

end result visual:

[image]

---

### update fix:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, {SPARKLINE(A1:INDEX(a, MAX(ROW(a)*(a<>""))-1), 
 {"charttype", "column"; "lastcolor", "green"; "ymax", MAX(a)}), 
 SPARKLINE(OFFSET(a, MAX(ROW(a)*(a<>""))-1,), 
 {"charttype", "column"; "color", "green"; 
  "ymax", MAX(a); "ymin", MIN(a)})})(A:A))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  What a cool approach!

Comment: @Newbie on a 2nd reading I noticed some errors which may occur. answer updated with better solution

Answer (score 1):

[image]

while this is possible to get, it is not doable with one single `SPARKLINE`. but you can use a column chart:

[image]

after some customization it could look like your desired output:

[image]

then double-click the last two columns and set them as alt color:

[image]

Comment: Good to know it’s not possible in sparkline which my application strictly needs.  Anyway thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Newbie i see, added alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this within one single sparkline, however if you can tolerate an additional column to the right what you could do is to to join two sparklines together horizontally using an array literal with first sparkline containing all data points up to the penultimate one and the second containing just the last data point. Then colour the second sparkline the same as the last data point of the first and resize the column width so the bar width matches the other data points.

Obviously this won't be possible in every context.